# User form is taking to long to execute

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I have this UserForm and  it's taking to long to look up. Is there any         way that I can reduce that time?

Here is the userform's textbox code where I put what I am looking for:

```
Private Sub TXTBUSCAART_Change()
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     Sheets("CONCAT").Select
     Range("A2").Select
     LSTART.Clear

     While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
         M = InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, UCase(TXTBUSCAART.Text))

         If M > 0 Then
             LSTART.ColumnCount = 9
             LSTART.AddItem         

             LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 0) = ActiveCell.Value
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
             LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 1) = ActiveCell.Value
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
             LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 2) = ActiveCell.Value
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
             LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 3) = ActiveCell.Value
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
             LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 4) = ActiveCell.Value
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
             LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 5) = ActiveCell.Value
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
             LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 6) = ActiveCell.Value
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
             LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 7) = ActiveCell.Value
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Select
             LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 8) = ActiveCell.Value
             ActiveCell.Offset(0, -6).Select
         End If

         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     Wend

     Sheets("REMITO").Select
     Range("A1").Select

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 End Sub
```

Comment: FYI, there is a code review site/section: Code Review at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where they help improve functional code. If your code is not functional, could you give a bit more information on what you're stuck on?

Comment: Also see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a lot faster to put the data into an array and loop through that - something like this (I think I got the columns right):

```
Private Sub TXTBUSCAART_Change()
    Dim rowCount As Long, itemCount As Long, counter As Long, n As Long
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataIn, dataOut()

    LSTART.Clear
    LSTART.ColumnCount = 9

    Set dataSheet = Sheets("CONCAT")
    With dataSheet

        rowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        itemCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A2:A" & rowCount), "*" & TXTBUSCAART.Text & "*")

        If itemCount > 0 Then
            ReDim dataOut(1 To itemCount, 1 To 9)
            dataIn = .Range("A2:I" & rowCount).Value
            counter = 1

            For n = 1 To UBound(dataIn)
                M = InStr(1, dataIn(1, 1), UCase(TXTBUSCAART.Text))
                If M > 0 Then
                    dataOut(counter, 1) = dataIn(n, 1)
                    dataOut(counter, 2) = dataIn(n, 3)
                    dataOut(counter, 3) = dataIn(n, 2)
                    dataOut(counter, 4) = dataIn(n, 4)
                    dataOut(counter, 5) = dataIn(n, 6)
                    dataOut(counter, 6) = dataIn(n, 5)
                    dataOut(counter, 7) = dataIn(n, 8)
                    dataOut(counter, 8) = dataIn(n, 9)
                    dataOut(counter, 9) = dataIn(n, 7)
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If
            Next

        LSTART.List = dataOut

        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select each cell before setting its value.  You can do it simply by referencing the cell object itself.  Using the `Cells` shortcut function, if you don't ask for a specific property, the cell's value is returned by default.

So for the loop portion, you might gain some speed doing this (especially if that `when` loop goes around many times):

```
 LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 0) = Cells(1, 2)
 LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 1) = Cells(1, 4)
 LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 2) = Cells(1, 3)
 LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 3) = Cells(1, 5)
 LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 4) = Cells(1, 7)
 LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 5) = Cells(1, 6)
 LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 6) = Cells(1, 9)
 LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 7) = Cells(1, 10)
 LSTART.List(LSTART.ListCount - 1, 8) = Cells(1, 8)
```

Double check my math - I just added and subtracted your offsets to generate this example code.